# Using ArcPy to iterate through each grid cell and make it current extent

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor, extents

I have a topology that covers a big area. I cannot validate all at once 'cause I get errors. So I've created a grid that covers the area.
Through a script runned from my .mxd I intend to:

1. iterate through each grid cell
2. set it as the current extent of the map,
3. use the tool "Validate Topology", having checked the option "VISIBLE_EXTENT".

The workflow sounds correct to me, but I'm blocked at the first two steps. Here's my code:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
gridLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Caroiaj_RO", df)[0] 


# Create SearchCursor
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(gridLayer, ("GridName2")) as cursor:

# Start a loop that iterates through all rows 
    for row in cursor:

    # Clause to select only the current record
        whereClause = ' "GridName2" = ' + str(row.GridName2)

        # Select Layer by attribute
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(gridLayer, "NEW_SELECTION", whereClause)

        df.extent = gridLayer.getSelectedExtent(True)

        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

del cursor, row
del mxd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following code.  First I ensure the first item in the TOC is my grid, and then I begin an edit session.  I then enter the following code in the python window in ArcMap, making sure to define the topology path.  I hope it helps.

```
import arcpy

# Find min and max values of a feature class field
def min_max(featureClass, fieldName):
    listItems = []
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(featureClass)
    for row in rows:
        listItems.append(row.getValue(fieldName))
    del rows
    listItems.sort()
    listMin = listItems[0]
    listMax = listItems[-1]
    return listMin, listMax

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, 'Layers')[0] # get top df in mxd
layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0] # get top layer in TOC
desc = arcpy.Describe(layer.dataSource)
fullpath = desc.catalogPath
counter, Max = min_max(fullpath, "OBJECTID") # get min and max values from FID field
topology = r"DEFINE_TOPOLOGY_PATH_HERE"
while counter <= Max:
    print("%s of %s" % (counter, Max))
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer, "NEW_SELECTION", '"OBJECTID" = ' + str(counter))
    df.extent = layer.getSelectedExtent()
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.ValidateTopology_management(topology, "VISIBLE_EXTENT")
    counter += 1
```

You may have to change 'OBJECTID' to fit your data.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're mixing up `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` and `arcpy.SearchCursor`. You can't do row.ColumnName on a list.
2. I don’t see the point of this script.  It'll pan through each extent, but not stop for any period of time. It'll basically draw a map on screen, then immediately hop to the next.

Try this:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
gridLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Caroiaj_RO", df)[0] 

# Create SearchCursor
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(gridLayer, ("GridName2")) as cursor:
    # Start a loop that iterates through all rows 
    for row in cursor:
        # Clause to select only the current record
        whereClause = ' "GridName2" = {}'.format(row[0])

        # Select Layer by attribute
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(gridLayer, "NEW_SELECTION", whereClause)

        df.extent = gridLayer.getSelectedExtent(True)
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```